# Jquery hide elements starting at nth. index

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML-Dom:

```
<nav class="menubar-first">
    <a class="w-nav-link menue" href="/" style="max-width: 940px;">Start</a>
    <div class="w-dropdown dropdown-bg" style="max-width: 940px;">
    <div class="w-dropdown dropdown-bg" style="max-width: 940px;">
    <a class="w-nav-link menue" href="/cafe/" style="max-width: 940px;">Café</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue" href="/web-shop/" style="max-width: 940px;">Web-Shop</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/aktuelles/" style="max-width: 940px;">Aktuelles</a>
    <div class="w-dropdown dropdown-bg" style="max-width: 940px;">
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/geschenkgutscheine/" style="max-width: 940px;">Geschenkgutscheine</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/tipps/" style="max-width: 940px;">Tipps</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/termine/" style="max-width: 940px;">Termine</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/service/" style="max-width: 940px;">Service</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/stellenangebote/" style="max-width: 940px;">Stellenangebote</a>
    <a class="w-nav-link menue w-hidden-main" href="/news/" style="max-width: 940px;">News</a>
</nav>
```

I want to add a class to the `a` and the `div`. I don't know if it will be an `a`-tag or a div, it is depending on the user, since it is a menu.

I managed to add the classes to the `a`-tags with this:

```
var i = 0;
$('.menuebar-first .w-nav-link').each(function() {
    i++;
    if (i >= 4) {
        $(this).addClass('w-hidden-main');
    }
});
```

This, however, does only include the `a`'s and not the `div`s.

Thank you

Comment: your heading "Jquery hide elements starting at nth. index" and question inside is not matching. what exactly you want to do?

Comment: but you `div`s dont have a class of `w-nav-link` so they wont be included

Comment: Keep in mind that each doc: `$.each([], function (index, element) {});`. So you can do `$.each($('.menuebar-first .w-nav-link'), function (i, element) {})`

Comment: you can use $('.menuebar-first').children() and iterate using each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just consider the children of `menubar-first` don't worry if it is a `anchor` of `div` if they are the only allowed children.

```
$('.menubar-first > *').slice(3).addClass('w-hidden-main')
```

else

```
$('.menubar-first').children('.w-nav-link, .w-dropdown').slice(3).addClass('w-hidden-main')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the `div`'s because they have a different class to the `a`'s, try:

```
var i = 0;

$('.menuebar-first .w-nav-link, .menuebar-first .w-dropdown').each(function() {
    i++;
    if (i >= 4) {
        $(this).addClass('w-hidden-main');
    }
});
```